# Correct way of "Absolute Import" in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

- Python 2.7.10
- In virtualenv
- Enable `from __future__ import absolute_import` in each module

The directory tree looks like:

```
Project/
    prjt/
        __init__.py
        pkg1/
            __init__.py
            module1.py
            tests/
                __init__.py
                test_module1.py
        pkg2/
            __init__.py
            module2.py
            tests/
                __init__.py
                test_module2.py
        pkg3/
            __init__.py
            module3.py
            tests/
                __init__.py
                test_module3.py
    data/
    log/
```

---

I tried to use the function `compute()` of `pkg2/module2.py` in `pkg1/module1.py` by writing like:

```
# In module1.py
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/Project/prjt')

from prjt.pkg2.module2 import compute
```

But when I ran `python module1.py`, the interpreter raised an ImportError that `No module named prjt.pkg2.module2`.

1. What is the correct way of "absolute import"? Do I have to add the path to `Project` to `sys.path`?
2. How could I run `test_module1.py` in the interactive interpreter? By `python prjt/pkg1/tests/test_module1.py` or `python -m prjt/pkg1/tests/test_module1.py`?

Comment: Yes, Project needs to be on the path if you are referencing it in an import. Otherwise just `from pkg2.module2...` etc.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you. Would you please specify "otherwise" situation?

Answer (score 15):

#### How python find module

*python will find module from `sys.path`, and the first entry `sys.path[0]` is '' means, python will find module from the current working directory*

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

and python find third-party module from `site-packages`

so to absolute import, you can

**append your package to the `sys.path`**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('the_folder_of_your_package')

import module_you_created

module_you_created.fun()
```

**export PYTHONPATH**

the PYTHONPATH will be imported into sys.path before execution

```
export PYTHONPATH=the_folder_of_your_package

import sys
[p for p in sys.path if 'the_folder_of_your_package' in p]
```

> How could I run test_module1.py in the interactive interpreter? By python Project/pkg1/tests/test_module1.py or python -m Project/pkg1/tests/test_module1.py?

you can use `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiomatic way, and use `python Project/pkg1/tests/test_module1.py`

```
if __name__ = '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I put the `sys.path.append('path/to/Project')` statement in every `.py` file in the projects? Or just put the statement in the `__init__.py` of module `Project`? Besides, should I append `path/to/Project` or `path/to/Project/Project`?

Comment: you can just put sys.path to the `__init__.py` of  top level package

Comment: I put `import sys` and `sys.path.append('/path/to/Project')` in the `prjt/__init__.py`. And then run in the terminal `cd /path/to/pkg1` and `python module1.py`. But the error `No module named prj.pkg2` was raised.

Comment: On the other hand, I did not specify `sys.path.append()` but run the terminal `export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/Project"`, everything worked fine. So I guess the `sys.path.append()` statement in the previous situation was not run. But I would not like to export bash variable. Would you please help me out of the `sys.path.append()` failure?

Answer (score 7):

If you add `sys.path.append('path/to/Project')` into `prjt/__init__.py`, you need to import submodules so: `from pkg2.module2 import compute` (without `prjt` specification) because `prjt` package import is in progress and the higher level folder is not in the `sys.path`. This is exactly what @Cissoid suggested.

BTW, `from __future__ import absolute_import` is not necessary for Py >= 3.0.

---

Answering your second question... I have very similar structure for unittests subfolder, so in the `pkg/unittests/testall.py` I wrote the following:

```
testfolder = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
project_root = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(testfolder, r"..\.."))
sys.path.append(project_root)
import pkg
```

I run it without `-m` option because it's unnecessary complication.

Comment: just : `from __future__ import absolute_import`  are unnecessary since python>=3.0, before that it's still required / making a diff.

Comment: You need to correct your answer according to @gst's comment. It may mislead people.

Answer (score 6):

Import the outer Project path.

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/Project')
```

Or import "compute" start from pkg2

```
from pkg2.module2 import compute
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

This will give absolute path

Answer (score 0):

Using explicit relative imports, this should work from `module1.py`:

```
from ..pkg2.module2 import compute()
```

This is cleaner than messing with `PYTHONPATH`...